# AlertDialog didn't appear (was in background)

Tags: android

I attempted to show an AlertDialog for my phone application using the code below. While my application ran to the entry point, the AlertDialog did not show up for user.

The phone screen changed to a dark color was locked. However, I can press phone's **Back** button to let the application go to next step like the behavior of **Cancel** function pressed.

The AlertDialog seems hidden in the application background. I would like to call it to foreground.

How to do it ?

By the way, there was no error message shown on the LogCat.

Could somebody point me out where I was wrong or what other information I can provide?

Thanks !

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Mainx.this);
builder1.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.str_sel_player));
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View functionListView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_pickitem_action,null); 
builder1.setView(functionListView);   
mlistView = (ListView) functionListView.findViewById(R.id.m_functions_listview); 
mlistView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,                 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mPlayers)); 
selDialog = builder1.create();
selDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are for calling the alert dialog method

```
AlertDialog diaBox = makeAndShowDialogBox();
diaBox.show();
```

## Alert Dialog Code

```
 private AlertDialog makeAndShowDialogBox(){
 AlertDialog myQuittingDialogBox =new AlertDialog.Builder(this) 
    //set message, title, and icon
    .setTitle(resource.getString(R.string.str_pick_app)) 
    .setMessage(resource.getString(R.string.savesettings)) 
    .setIcon(R.drawable.menu_settings)

    .setPositiveButton(resource.getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) { 

            //write code as acc to your requirement

            dialog.dismiss();

        }   

    })

    .create();
//startActivity(intet);
    return myQuittingDialogBox;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Ram's quick response ! The initialization of appBackDialog for my application was coded while the Activity start already(means it is global varable for this Activity).  and the "appBackDialog.show();" was coded in the end of my code. I am not sure what's the difference or concerns with your suggestions ?

Comment: By the way, I do not need the DialogInterface to implement the Yes/No Buttons. This AlertDialog Box will show function itmes list for user selection only.

Comment: Because I corrected the posted code section. The "appBackDialog.show();" shound change as "selDialog.show();" for my prevouse Comment. Sorry for the inturruption !

Answer (score 0):

It is strange.

You can try to use showDialog() together with onCreateDialog()

override Activity's

Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)

then invoke showDialog(int id)

Comment: Hi Jiang, thanks for the suggestion ! The Dialog box still was  not shown by implement the method provided. It is hidden in background as before.